# how to export html data to pdf in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

this is my html code where i rendered all `json` data from `.js` file but getting

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.keys ()
>       at DocMeasure.measureNode (pdfmake.js:15647)
>       at DocMeasure.measureDocument (pdfmake.js:15635)
>       at LayoutBuilder.tryLayoutDocument (pdfmake.js:15088)
>       at LayoutBuilder.layoutDocument (pdfmake.js:15076)
>       at PdfPrinter.createPdfKitDocument (pdfmake.js:2130)
>       at Document._createDoc (pdfmake.js:82)
>       at Document.getDataUrl (pdfmake.js:177)
>       at Document.open (pdfmake.js:109)
>       at l.$scope.openPdf (app.js:29)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="raj.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="pdfDemo">
  <div ng-controller="pdfCtrl">
          <div id="pdfContent">
                  <table id="example-table">
                            <thead>
                            <th>firstName</th>
                            <th>lastName</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                            <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.lastName}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.gender}}</td>
                            <td>{{emp.mobile}}</td>
                            </tr>

                            </tbody>

                  </table>
          </div>
    <button ng-click="openPdf()">Open Pdf</button>
    <button ng-click="downloadPdf()">Download Pdf</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`pdfmake`](http://pdfmake.org/#/), to export the pdf

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
   function($scope) {
     $scope.data=  [{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Safi","statutImp":"operationnel"}];
     
     $scope.export = function(){
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500,
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
            }
        });
     }
   }
 ]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.22/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="listController">
    <div id="exportthis">
      {{data}}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="export()">export</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah ! thank sajeetharan its working fine but when i replace code something like this its not getting

Comment: function($scope) {
     $scope.data=  [{firstName:"rajeh",lastName:"gatla",gender:"mgale",mobile:"8143445171"},
   {firstName:"sathi",lastName:"wesd",gender:"madfgle",mobile:"8143445171"},
    {firstName:"gjds",lastName:"hs",gender:"madfhsdfle",mobile:"8143445171"},
  {firstName:"dfdff",lastName:"gahgsftla",gender:"mdfsdsale",mobile:"8143445171"},
   {firstName:"dsfsd",lastName:"gatWERWDla",gender:"madfshfle",mobile:"8143445171"},
    {firstName:"dfagdsew",lastName:"gatlgfha",gender:"mdfgdfale",mobile:"8143445171"}];

Comment: <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
       <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
       <td>{{emp.lastName}}</td>
       <td>{{emp.gender}}</td>
       <td>{{emp.mobile}}</td>
       </tr>
       
       </tbody>

Comment: @Sajeetharan The only pdf exporter where more than 4 columns can be exported. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Sajeetharan But when the number of rows are increasing, pdf is blank.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise): invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)` error

Comment: @Sajeetharan Add `<canvas></canvas>` at the end of your div and it should work.

Comment: in the demo the exported pdf is not very clean

Comment: @Sajeetharan -+1, I know its an old thread, but i have a question on this..How to show each iterating data(ng-repeat) of angularjs in individual pdf pages using pdfmake while exporting the data to pdf? Please find the plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/qrYQuT1Vyl5LVCDwS36c?p=preview , when user click on export button, details[0] should be shown in page1 and details[1] should be shown in page2, is that possible?

Comment: @Sajid -As you suggested, i have kept <canvas></canvas> at the end of the <div>, but still the PDF is blank when trying to export large data.Any inputs?
Please find my demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/h8cJbz3MlLJOl87UusZp?p=preview . It opens a blank PDF, but if the data is less it exports the data.

Comment: Without converting data can we able to convert html to pdf

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code to export HTML table to EXcel, CSV, Pdf, Doc

https://plnkr.co/edit/HmKBjYmJNjp8mPzIlg52?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Export HTML Table to Excel, Pdf, CSV and Doc</p>

<table class="export-table" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Employee ID</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in reportData">
              <td>{{item.EmployeeID}}</td>
              <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
              <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
              <td>{{item.Salary}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<a href="#" data-ng-click="exportAction('csv')"> Export CSV</a><br/><br/>
<a href="#" data-ng-click="exportAction('excel')"> Export Excel</a><br/><br/>
<a href="#" data-ng-click="exportAction('doc')"> Export Doc</a><br/><br/>
<a href="#" data-ng-click="exportAction('pdf')"> Export Pdf</a><br/><br/>
```

Comment: How to have more than 4 columns in pdf export?

Comment: i think this library exports only table, not even a single header or something, i was looking for invoicing.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this:

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

and then you can use in your controller like this:

```
 $scope.HTMLclick = function () {
                var pdf = new jsPDF();
                pdf.addHTML(($("#pdfContent")[0]), { pagesplit: true }, function () {
                    pdf.save('myfilename' + '.pdf');
                });

            };
```

Comment: Hey, I'm using jsPDF in my angular 1.6 project.
Do you know How can I print all of my HTML + CSS to a pdf file? TNX

Comment: @mashiah, using jsPDF we cannot render CSS i guess.

Answer (score 1):

**FOR ANGULAR**

STEP 1: `npm install jspdf-autotable`

or in **index.html** into `<head></head>` add: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.2/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js">`

STEP 2:in **Angular-cli.json** add:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
],
```

STEP 3: **app.component.ts or any other component** aff below imports

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
declare var jsPDF: any;
```

STEP 4: For test put in your component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  public columns: string[] = ['Name', 'Phone', 'Whatsapp'];
  public data: string[] = ['Diego Venâncio', '79999565796', '79912345678'];

  constructor() {
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    doc.autoTable(columns, data);
    doc.save("table.pdf");
  }
```

}

[more details?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-autotable)

Comment: I did  same thing in my angular 5 project and I am getting ERROR ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
    at DashboardComponent.downloadPdf

Answer (score 1):

**Best and feasible way is to use window.print() function. Which does not require any library**

**Pros**

1.No external library require.

2.We can print only selected parts of body also.

3.No css conflicts and js issues.

4.Core html/js functionality

---Simple add below code

**CSS** to

```
@media print {
        body * {
            visibility: hidden; // part to hide at the time of print
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; // not necessary use         
               if colors not visible
        }

        #printBtn {
            visibility: hidden !important; // To hide 
        }

        #page-wrapper * {
            visibility: visible; // Print only required part
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
        }
    }
```

**JS code -** Call below function on btn click

```
$scope.printWindow = function () {
  window.print()
}
```

**Note: Use !important in every css object**

**Example -**

```
.legend  {
  background: #9DD2E2 !important;
}
```