# How to convert an HTML string (which comes as a response from API) to pdf and download in AngularJs?

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to download a receipt as PDF. The API gives an html string in response. Now, I need to convert this HTML to PDF.

This is my AngularJs code.

```
vm.downloadReceipt = function (id) {
    angularService.getReceipt(id).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.fromHTML(response.data);
            doc.save('receipt.pdf');
        } else {
           showError();
        }
    });
}
```

I get this error in console when i run it.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at j (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at k (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at k (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at jspdf.min.js:202
    at l (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at d (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at m (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at Object.t.fromHTML (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at occupant.component.js:101
    at angular.js:13170
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395566/how-to-export-html-data-to-pdf-in-angularjs

Comment: this does not solve the problem. The html string comes in the variable _response.data_

Comment: What's `at occupant.component.js:101`? Some a variable is undefined and you try to read property 'name' of it.

Comment: @phuwin At occupant.component.js:101, there is this line `doc.fromHTML(response.data);`

Comment: Could you check this https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/516 I think there's some problem with the HTML that you try to generate a pdf from.